# Possible to change characters in input to Circles?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is just a general/vague question,

If i had a textarea...

```
<textarea class="mybox">
    myfirststring secondstring
</textarea>
```

Is it possible to use javascript/jquery so that after the first string is typed 'myfirststring'/spacebar has been hit that you can somehow convert the remaining text in the field into protexted text, as though it was a password and you want to hide the characters?

Comment: Its just for a personal experiment, just seeing what I can and can't do at the moment

Comment: ah, I didn't see your response. I don't think it's a good idea. Added my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/reec7/2/

It's a good start, if this is what you are looking for:

```
$(function(){
    $("textarea").keypress(function(e){
        if( e.which != 32 ) return true;

        var words = $(this).val().split(" ");

        // Make list
        if( ! $(this).data("list") )
        {
            $(this).data("list", []);
        }
        var list = $(this).data("list");

        // Save words
        $.each(words, function(k, v){
            if( v.indexOf("*") == -1 )
            {
                 list.push(v);   
            }
        });


        // Replace with *
        $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^\s]/g, "*"));
    });

    $("input:button").click(function(){
         var list = $("textarea").data("list");
         var str = "";
        $.each(list, function(k, v){
         str += v + "\n";
        });
        alert(str);
    });
});
```

Comment: It's a good start, although it "breaks" (i.e., does not reflect the *real* state) when I hit the backspace key.

Answer (score 2):

Probably yes by capturing keypress events inside the textarea and deciding individually what to do with them, but it feels like a bad idea to me: It would be terribly complicated (you'd have to store the protected text elsewhere; you'd run into huge problems when people leave and re-enter the page; etc.) and it would never be as well protected as a native password field.

Is there no way to do what you want with two separate text fields, one of which is a `type="password"` one and gets shown dynamically if the user types `myfirststring` into the first one?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible. For instance, you could replace the typed characters with asterisks (or whatever character renders as a "circle" in the relevant font), and store what was actually typed in a JS variable or a hidden input field.